# Linq Expression to Display

Tags: c#, linq

Quick Question:

I want to display certain properties of certain entities:

```
public void DisplayEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> properties)
{
    // access the properties values

    Console.Write(propertyValue);
}
```

So I can simply do this:

```
DisplayEntity(Contact contact, c => c.Name);
DisplayEntity(Contact contact, c => c.Name, c => c.Tel);
```

I'm not sure how to write the `DisplayEntity` function so that you can do this.

***ANSWER***

Based on Florian's answer, I slightly condensed it, in keeping with the lambda expression stuff:

```
static void WriteEntity<T>(T entity, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] properties)
{
    properties.ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            var f = x.Compile();
            MemberExpression me;
            switch (x.Body.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Convert:
                case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
                    var ue = x.Body as UnaryExpression;
                    me = ((ue != null) ? ue.Operand : null) as MemberExpression;
                    break;
                default:
                    me = x.Body as MemberExpression;
                    break;
            }
            var memberInfo = me.Member;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", memberInfo.Name, f(entity));
        });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
void ShowPropertyName<T1, T2>(T1 p, params Expression<Func<T1, T2>>[] properties)
    {
        foreach (var e in properties)
        {
            var f = e.Compile();
            var memberExpression = e.Body as MemberExpression;
            var memberInfo = memberExpression.Member;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", memberInfo.Name, f(p));
        }
    }
```

This would give you the name of the property and its value.

**UPDATE:**

Example

```
class Test
{
    public int P1 { get; set; }
    public int P2 { get; set; }
}

var test = new Test {P1 = 5, P2 = 3};

ShowPropertyName(test, t => t.P1);
ShowPropertyName(test, t => t.P2, t => t.P1);
```

Result

```
P1: 5
P2: 3
P1: 5
```

**UPDATE:**
Disclaimer: This only works for properties directly on p, every thing else should be catched.

**UPDATE:**

Example 2 - Allowing more then one Property type in one call:

```
void ShowPropertyName<T1>(T1 p, params Expression<Func<T1, object>>[] properties)
    {
        foreach (var e in properties)
        {
            var f = e.Compile();

            MemberExpression memberExpression;
            if (e.Body is UnaryExpression)
            {
                var unaryExpression = e.Body as UnaryExpression;
                memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
            }
            else if(e.Body is MemberExpression)
            {
                memberExpression = e.Body as MemberExpression;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unsupported Body expression of type {0}", e.Body.GetType());
                return;
            }
            var memberInfo = memberExpression.Member;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", memberInfo.Name, f(p));
        }
    }
```

Test class:

```
class Test
{
    public int P1 { get; set; }
    public int P2 { get; set; }
    public string P3 { get; set; }
}
```

Execution:

```
        var test = new Test {P1 = 5, P2 = 3, P3 = "hello"};

        ShowPropertyName(test, t => t.P1);
        ShowPropertyName(test, t => t.P2, t => t.P1, t=> t.P3);
```

Result:

```
P1: 5
P2: 3
P1: 5
P3: hello
```

Comment: I like this, I changed it to this: `properties.ToList().ForEach(x =>
                {
                    var f = x.Compile();
                    var memberExpression = x.Body as MemberExpression;
                    var memberInfo = memberExpression.Member;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", memberInfo.Name, f(userprofile));
                });`

Comment: Sounds fine to me. Happy to help.

Comment: What if `P2` is a `string`?

Comment: Then you would have to split the second call into 2 calls, or go the hard way and only use Expression, and invoking the compilation your self.

Comment: `e.Compile();` is a very expensive and absolutely useless operation.

Comment: Yes it's expensive, but far from useless. And the only way to make the shown code possible without supplying the Func a second time.

Comment: @FlorianDohrendorf , haha I was just about to add my own answer update the `MemberExpression` stuff because it was hitting a null expcetion or something, but it look likes you have already beaten me too it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void DisplayEntity<TEntity, TProperty>(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>[] properties)
{
  foreach (var propertyValue in properties)
  {
    var m = propertyValue.Compile();
    Console.Write(m(entity));
  }
}
//...
DisplayEntity<Contact, string>(contact, c => c.Name);
```

While this gets your code to compile and work somehow, it's rather useless, as the same effect can be achieved by:

```
public void Display(object property)
{
Console.Write(property);
}
//...
Display(contact.Name);
```

If you want to stick to lambdas (for educational purposes) maybe this will be better:

```
public void DisplayEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] properties)
{
  foreach (var propertyValue in properties)
  {
    var m = propertyValue.Compile();
    Console.Write(m(entity));
  }
}
//...
DisplayEntity<Contact>(contact, c => c.Name, c => c.IsEnabled);
```

Comment: Well, ehm, I think you'll need to involve `entity` somehow.

Comment: I fixed it to compile. Note the "[]" parenthesis after params, and expression compilation.

Comment: But what do i pass as TProperty?

Comment: You need to pass type of the property you're displaying. I've added an example. That's not very convenient and so I fail to understand why would you need such method.

Comment: I want to learn more about using expressions etc, and I quite like the idea of just doing `c => c.Name`

Comment: All right then. The only one drawback of this approach is that all properties need to have the same type. You could omit TProperty type and use Func<TEntity, object> - this way it would be more convenient.

Comment: What would m(entity) produce, how could you show the property name@

Comment: It produces the value of the property. If you want the name of the property refer to Florian Dohrendorf's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to do the job in a very simple way;

```cs
public static void DisplayEntity<T>(T entity, params Func<T, Object>[] parm)
{
    foreach (var func in parm)
        Console.WriteLine(func(entity));
}
```

Comment: `dynamic` would be more convenient `Console.WriteLine(func(entity));`

Comment: @CuongLe The `ToString()` call is just to make the conversion obvious, removed it since it's not necessary.